# Configuring QGIS new OAuth2 support for WMS or WFS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wfs, authentication

Has anyone successfully configured QGIS new OAuth2 support for a WMS or WFS service?

I have an ArcGIS 10.6.1 service published as a WFS service but cannot get past the OAuth2 authentication.

Answer (score 0):

> The OGC specifications for WMS and WFS do not allow OAuth 2
> authentication. In an environment where ArcGIS Server is federated
> with Portal for ArcGIS, secure WMS or WFS services require
> authentication from Portal for ArcGIS and support OAuth 2. Until the
> OGC specifications and corresponding client applications are updated
> to support OAuth 2, secure OGC services can only be provided from an
> unfederated ArcGIS Server using web-tier authentication. This is a
> known limitation associated with OGC services and not with Portal for
> ArcGIS.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017300